# AMD GPU-dkms not building in kernel 5.8/5.8-xanmod

Tags: drivers, kernel, 20.04, amdgpu, dkms

I recently bought the ASUS TUF Gaming FA506IH with Ryzen 5 4600H and dedicated NVIDIA gtx 1650Ti. I am not much of a gamer so I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and thought of not using Nvidia drivers (because of compatibility issue with newer kernels) until I needed it, and just go with the integrated Radeon graphics. However, I noticed that newer gen Radeon graphics are not supported in 5.4 kernel so I installed mainline 5.8 kernel and after installing the amdgpu drivers, it seems to work fine, but I am getting an error with dkms saying it is not supported in kernel 5.8. I also tried xanmod kernel 5.8, but still the same issue. This is the error message that I get when amdgpu tries to build its package on this kernel.

```
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.0.15-1098277) ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.0.15-1098277
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.0.15-1098277 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.16-xanmod1
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.8.16-xanmod1
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.16-xanmod1 is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.16-xanmod1 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.0.15-1098277/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.0.15-1098277); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get the same error when I try installing amdgpu on kernel 5.8.*-generic.

Comment: you need kernel-headers too. http://deb.xanmod.org/pool/main/l/linux-5.8.16-xanmod1/

Comment: I installed kernel-headers and then again re-installed amdgpu. But still not working. Same issue.

Comment: sorry not enough coffee.  kernel package linux-headers-5.8.16-xanmod1 is not supported.

Comment: I have a similar problem with a Thinkpad T14s and Ryzen 7. You can install `amdgpu` without `dkms` with the command `./amdgpu-install --no-dkms`. However this does not work with the pro version of the driver.

Comment: @red_trumpet Well, I read somewhere that you don't need any proprietary drivers for the newer renoir graphics to work, the support actually comes out-of-the-box on kernel >= 5.7. So, I just removed amdgpu, using `amdgpu uninstall` and everything works fine now. I am just wondering is there anything extra that you get if you install amdgpu using (`./amdgpu-install --no-dkms`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While searching more about this topic. I came to know that you don't really need to install any proprietary drivers for the newer gen AMD Renoir graphics to work on any kernel >= 5.7, because the support already comes out-of-the-box.
So I just uninstalled amdgpu using `amdgpu-uninstall` and everything works fine now.

---

As suggested by @red_trumpet in the comments section, you can also install the driver without dkms with the command `./amdgpu-install --no-dkms`. You can also specify an opencl installation using `./amdgpu-install --opencl=pal,legacy --no-dkms`. I've tested this, and have been using this for two months now.

**NOTE:** This does not work with the pro version of the driver.

Comment: Does opencl work?

Comment: Yep. you can use `./amdgpu-install --opencl=pal,legacy --no-dkms` to specify opencl installation.