# Laptop screen not working, just HDMI output, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I have a dual boot Ubuntu/W10 on a MSI Bravo Laptop with an AMD CPU and AMD GPU.

Laptop screen only shows an underscore on the upper left corner and the rest is black after I choose to boot with Ubuntu. The only output I get is when I connect an external monitor via HDMI and everything seems to work ok, but settings only detect one display.

I see lots of posts about this with Nvidia cards but only managed to get [this](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation) and tried Methods 1 and 2 but none of them seem to work.

None of this happens when I boot with Windows 10, but need Ubuntu for work. Any suggestions? Do you need more info or any command output?

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Upstream Port of PCI Express Switch (rev c1)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 XL Downstream Port of PCI Express Switch
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] (rev c1)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 HDMI Audio
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c6)
07:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
07:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
07:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir USB 3.1
07:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
07:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
08:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
08:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Output of `xrandr --prop`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
    non-desktop: 0 
        supported: 0, 1
   1920x1080     59.96*+
```

After getting an answer here:

I downloaded the drivers from [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20) and followed the instructions. Had to install it with `--no-dkms` as I ran into the same problems as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287904/amd-gpu-dkms-not-building-in-kernel-5-8-5-8-xanmod).

Now the laptop display works, but not the external monitor.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `lspci` and `xrandr --prop`? The first command will show the model of the video card (and other hardware), the second will show information about the connected display devices.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! @Matigo

Comment: I just got the same issue, but for a ThinkPad with an Nvidia card. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Apparently yes since I installed some automatic Ubuntu update. Not sure if that was the cause but it prompted me to restart and now it's working. Also I disabled secure booting from the BIOS because WiFi was not being detected from time to time. @Mr.Goferito

Answer (score 0):

I kinda had the same issue with my Laptop (AMD Rayzen 5 4500U with Ubuntu 20.04). Once it updated to the 5.13 kernel's version, my HDMI port kept working just fine, but my laptop display was out of order. We managed to fix the issue by removing the `*5.13*` version from the Ubuntu 20.04 and using the 5.11 version as a standard. It's now properly working, both laptop display and HDMI port (LG monitor as a device). I hope this can help.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem on my pc with amd rx580 gpu. It could not see my 4k monitor but worked fine with old 1360x768 tv. Proprietary AMDGPU-PRO drivers installation helped me. They are already aviable for Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I downloaded the drivers from [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20) and followed the instructions. Had to install it with `--no-dkms` as I ran into the same problems as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287904/amd-gpu-dkms-not-building-in-kernel-5-8-5-8-xanmod).

Now the laptop display works, but not the external monitor.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem, but on a Thinkpad laptop, with an Nvidia card. External monitor working fine.

To me the solution was to remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I created that file from the Nvidia Settings application, trying to optimize performance.

I found a way to do the optimizations without creating that file, so everything is back to normal.

Comment: Solutions, if any, are hardware specific. Posting an answer regarding Nvidia graphics in a question about AMD graphics is misleading and counterproductive.

Comment: @ChanganAuto why is it hardware specific? He could have made the same mistake by crafting that file, and just booting without it would get him on a clean state again. I'm not discussing the internals of that file, just suggesting that loading the defaults again may solve his issue, like it did to me.

Comment: It is hardware specific and dependent on drivers (kernel modules) as you should have figured out by now from the comment reply above. And no they clearly didn't do what you did. And if you suspected that could be the case you could and should have asked for clarification (that's what comments are for) and that would have then avoided posting and irrelevant and misleading answer.